# Row Data Bound in ASP.NET Grid View C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view and need to bind IsActive field.But from the database it comes as 1 or 0.

Error shows `System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'`

### Grid

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="IsActive" HeaderText="Status">
                                    <ItemStyle Width="200px" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
```

### Code

```
 protected void grid1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (((int)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "IsActive") == 1))
            {
                e.Row.Cells[12].Text = "Active";

            }
            else
            {
                e.Row.Cells[12].Text = "Inactive";
          }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try grabbing the underlying data item first and then checking for it.

```
protected void grid1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView rowView = null;
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // Retrieve the underlying data item 
        rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

        // Make sure we can parse and compare what we get.
        if (int.TryParse(rowView["IsActive"].ToString(), out int isActive) && isActive == 1)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[12].Text = "Active";

        }
        else
        {
            e.Row.Cells[12].Text = "Inactive";
        }

    }
}
```